# Link error with GetACP under mingw64 (mingw-builds)

Tags: linker, configure, gdal, wow64, mingw-w64

I was trying to build gdal-1.10.0
(http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource) using mingw64 (from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/
x64-4.8.0-release-posix-seh-rev2.7z). I have compiled gdal-1.10.0 under the
standard MinGW (32-bit) version without a problem.

The reason I have to switch to mingw64 is that the standard 32-bit MinGW distribution
does not support c++11 features like `std::thread`, and (I suspect) other features as
well. But I get an linking error in the end telling me something about

```
undefined reference to '__imp_GetACP'
```

(or a different decorated name if I use the 32-bit variant from
mingw64/mingw-builds). BTW, I tried different versions of mingw64, including
64-bit, 32-bit, seh, sjlj, but all gave the same error about `GetACP()`.

I did some homework and found some instructions for a similar compilation task:
http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/mingw64_how_to.html#env
According to the above website, it seems that they suggest the problem has to do
with WOW64 and the correct version of windows dll files cannot be used because
windows automatically determines it for you depending on whether a 32-bit or
64-bit application making the call. This is supposedly a problem for mingw64
because the compiler gcc is 64-bit but msys is hopelessly 32-bit.

But since I tried 32-bit versions as well, the above does not seem to explain
the error.
Even more, I tried in a dirty way to comment out all calls to `GetACP()`,
because I don't really care about code pages and all that for my purposes.
Strangely enough, compilation is OK (on a fresh source just with the `GetACP()`'s commented out), but the same link error is still reported. I checked that `libkernel32.a`, `libiconv.a` are in the `lib` folder, and also followed the instructions in the blog above to copy dll's out from
`c:\windows\system32` and place them in mingw subfolders with appropriate renaming. The link error remains. This is where I stopped hacking after spending almost two days on this without success. I can't understand why the entire source-code does not contain a single call to the function and I am still getting the link error.

Can anyone explain what might have caused this issue between gdal and mingw64,
and how to fix it?

Also, a general question about mingw64 is that is it really able to support
posix functions? I see package names such as
x64-4.8.0-release-posix-seh-rev2.7z, but I remember that the MinGW people said
they will never support full posix.

P.S.
I am testing this on a Windows Server 2008 R2, 64-bit.

---

Update:
The complete steps for building gdal-1.10.0 under MinGW64 (mingw-builds) are:

```
$./configure
```

Then,
Edit GDALmake.opt, Find GDAL_ROOT and replace the cygwin drive format with dos/mingw format, e.g.
Change:

```
GDAL_ROOT  = /d/temp/build/gdal-1.10.0
```

to

```
GDAL_ROOT =  d:/temp/build/gdal-1.10.0
```

Replace

```
CONFIG_LIBS =   $(GDAL_ROOT)/$(LIBGDAL)
```

with

```
CONFIG_LIBS =   $(GDAL_ROOT)/$(LIBGDAL)   -liconv
```

Finally,

```
$ make && make install && cp apps/*.exe /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have accidentally encountered the same problem. 
Maybe this is a MinGW bug or bad configuration files, but the solution is to add 
**-liconv** to the end of linker flags, for example, replace

```
CONFIG_LIBS =   $(GDAL_ROOT)/$(LIBGDAL)
```

with

```
CONFIG_LIBS =   $(GDAL_ROOT)/$(LIBGDAL)   -liconv
```

in GDALmake.opt file (found by searching Mingw directory for GetACP in files).

Comment: This is excellent. Tested using x64-4.8.1-release-posix-seh-rev0 (mingw-builds). Note: it seems that there was already an -liconv in GDALmake.opt. But, somehow it wasn't picked up under MinGW64 (per mingw-builds).

Comment: So, why this bug occurs?

Comment: Had the similar situation with such error. Error disappeared after changing order of adding of iconv (from cmake) to last position.