# Mingw / Boost / C++ - link error (undefined reference to __imp_GetACP) when using Boost Locale

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, mingw, ld

When I try to use Boost::locale package in my C++ project (something as simple, as this is):

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
. . . . . .
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale lx = gen("rus");
std::locale::global(lx);
```

I got a link error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable DBMSProject.exe
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib\libiconv.a(localcharset.o):localcharset.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `__imp_GetACP'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\DBMSProject.dir\build.make:122: DBMSProject.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:92: CMakeFiles/DBMSProject.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:99: CMakeFiles/DBMSProject.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:134: DBMSProject] Error 2
```

My setup:

- Windows 10 x64
- Mingw x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0 (gcc 8.1.0)
- CMake 3.17.0-rc2, its options: `-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="valid-path-to-built-boost-libs" -DBoost_COMPILER=mgw81`
- Boost 1.72.0 built with gcc 8.1.0 from above (command to build was `b2 --build-dir="..." --prefix="..." toolset=gcc install --build-type=complete -j 4`)

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(DBMSProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}\\cmake)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -liconv")

find_package(Boost CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS locale regex) # yes, I also tried regex, and everything was OK
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(DBMSProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(DBMSProject -static)
target_link_libraries(DBMSProject Boost::locale Boost::regex)
```

So, the question is: how can I make it to link properly? I already tried to google this problem, but nothing seems as the solution to my problem.

Maybe it's a kbown problem, a bug?

I haven't installed ICU on my system, maybe it's the case?

Maybe I should link Boost.locale library dynamically instead of doing it statically? If so, how can I do it (because there is a plenty of boost locale libs in its build directory)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to link against iconv, worked in my case.

[Link error with GetACP under mingw64 (mingw-builds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558813/link-error-with-getacp-under-mingw64-mingw-builds)